# Proving there is some $M>0$ such that $B(x, y)\leq M\|x\|\|y\|$ for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to solve this exercise.

> Let $X, Y$ and $Z$ be Banach spaces and suppose $B: X\times Y\rightarrow Z$ is a continuous bilinear form. Show there is some $M>0$ such that $B(x, y)\leq M\|x\|\|y\|$ for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

I do not see where to start. Help is needed.

Comment: The cool thing is that this holds even if we just assume that $B$ is continuous in each variable.

Answer (score 1):

Using the max norm on the product space, the bilinearity and continuity of $B$, we can find a neighborhood $N_{\delta}(0,0)$ such that $|B(x,y)|<1$ whenever $x,y\in N_{\delta}(0,0)$.

Then, $|B(x,y)|=B\left(\frac{\|x\|}{\delta}\,\frac{\delta x}{\|x\|}, \frac{\|y\|}{\delta}\,\frac{\delta y}{\|y\|}\right)=\frac{\|x\|\|y\|}{\delta^2}B\left(\frac{\delta x}{\|x\|},\frac{\delta y}{\|y\|}\right)<\frac{\|x\|\|y\|}{\delta^2}\cdot 1=\frac{\|x\|\|y\|}{\delta^2}.$ So, we may take $M=1/\delta^2.$

Answer (score 0):

If this is not true then there exist $x_n,y_n$ such that $|B(x_n,y_n)| >n \|x_n\|\|y_n\|$ for all $n$. Let $u_n=\frac {x_n} {n^{1/4} \|x_n\|}$ and $v_n=\frac {y_n} {n^{1/4} \|y_n\|}$. Check that $u_n \to 0, v_n \to 0$ and $|B(u_n,v_n)| \to \infty$ which is  a contradiction.